# Remove pre-loader animations when all assets on page become available

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom, video

This code starts when the page loads and when all assets become available, it removes pre-loader animation and page becomes visible.
I know some functions has code repetition, but it can await refactoring stage. For now, I want to understand the basics of good code architecture creation.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

    /* object with assets and related methods */
    var elements = {
        _images : document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
        _videos : document.getElementsByTagName('video'),

        getImages: function() {
            return this._images;
        },

        getVideos: function() {
            return this._videos;
        },

        getTotalLength: function() {
            var result  = 0,
                keysArr = Object.keys(this);

            for (var i = 0; i < keysArr.length; i++) {
                if (typeof this[keysArr[i]] !== "function") {
                    result += this[keysArr[i]].length;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    };

    /* object with counter and related methods (maybe this should be inside another object) */
    var counter = {
        _counter: 0,
        incrementCounter: function() {
            this._counter++;
        },
        getCounter: function() {
            return this._counter;
        }
    };

    /* I think this two functions should compose another object */
    function imagesLoader() { // 1
        var imagesArr = elements.getImages();

        for (var i = 0, len = imagesArr.length; i < len; i++) {

            imagesArr[i].addEventListener('load', loadHandler);
            imagesArr[i].removeAttribute('srcset');
        }
    }

    function videosLoader() { // 2
        var videosArr = elements.getVideos();

        for (var i = 0, len = videosArr.length; i < len; i++) {
            var src = videosArr[i].getAttribute('data-src');

            videosArr[i].addEventListener('canplay', loadHandler);
            videosArr[i].setAttribute('src', src);
        }
    }

    /* this function removes CSS classes that block page rendering */
    function showPage() {
        setInterval(function() {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('html-loading');
            document.body.classList.remove('body-pause');
        }, 500);
    }

    /* general event handler */
    function loadHandler() {
        counter.incrementCounter();
        if (counter.getCounter() === elements.getTotalLength()) {
            showPage();
        }
    }

    /* This code starts the whole process */
    imagesLoader();
    videosLoader();
})();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Code Review!  Please review [How do I ask a good Question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Specifically, you will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. This also applies to the title.